# lsof doesn't show up my djvu files

Tags: grep, lsof, djvu

I am trying to print the `djvu` file names that are currently running on either `okular` or `atril`, but when I do `lsof | grep ".djvu$"` then I am getting no output in the terminal, where the same command works for `pdf` files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- if the application is running as a different user, you will need `sudo`:

  ```
  sudo lsof | grep ".djvu$"
  ```
- if some of the file extension is capital, you need to `-i` in `grep` to ignore case:

  ```
  sudo lsof | grep -i ".djvu$"
  ```
- the dot at the beginning of `.djvu$` will match any character (though this probably won't cause false positives in your case); what you probably mean is `\.djvu$`
- I recommend putting regular expressions in single quotes rather than double quotes because the dollar sign has special meaning for the Linux shell:

  ```
  sudo lsof | grep -i '\.djvu$'
  ```
- *(updated from `ps` to `pgrep` thanks to comment from qubert)* if the application reads the files into memory and then closes it, the `lsof` won't see it, but `ps` (process list) will; `pgrep` is the proper tool to search through running processes; try:

  ```
  pgrep --list-full --full --ignore-case '\.djvu'
  ```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but again, though I have a `djvu` file open, I get nothing.

Comment: @Ritajit Kundu - I don't have that reader. It's possible that the application opens the file, reads the contents into memory, and then closes the file before you run `lsof` so that you don't have a chance to see it when it's open. I added a 5th bullet to my list above which may work if this is the case.

Comment: the library used to render .djvus (libdjvulibre) is always using separate threads to render each page, and it's those threads that open the file (they're not passed an open fd from the parent), and exit when they're finished rendering.

Comment: instead of `ps -ef | grep ...`, use `pgrep -afi '\.djvu\>'`; or if you insist on using `ps`, use `ps -wwef | grep ...`; otherwise it will truncate the command line and may miss if eg. a .djvu file name is longer than 80 characters.

Comment: @qubert - Good point; thanks. I've been meaning to learn how to use `pgrep`. I updated my answer accordingly.